# how to convert Int32 value to CGFloat in swift?

Tags: swift, ios8.1, cgfloat, int32

Here my code.  I am passing two values into `CGRectMake(..)` and getting and error.

```
let width = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(device.activeFormat.formatDescription as CMVideoFormatDescriptionRef!).width
// return Int32 value

let height = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(device.activeFormat.formatDescription as CMVideoFormatDescriptionRef!).height
// return Int32 value

myLayer?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)
// returns error: '`Int32`' not convertible to `CGFloat`
```

How can I convert `Int32` to `CGFloat` to not return an error?

Comment: Direct `Int` to `CGFloat` conversion might be time consuming. Consider using different methods if API is available. For example, you can create `CGSize` from `Int`, and then do `let dividedSize =size.applying(.init(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5))`, instead of converting Int's to CGFloat for dividing.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

To convert between numerical data types create a new instance of the target type, passing the source value as parameter. So to convert an `Int32` to a `CGFloat`:

```
let int: Int32 = 10
let cgfloat = CGFloat(int)
```

In your case you can either do:

```
let width = CGFloat(CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(device.activeFormat.formatDescription as CMVideoFormatDescriptionRef!).width)
let height = CGFloat(CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(device.activeFormat.formatDescription as CMVideoFormatDescriptionRef!).height)

myLayer?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)
```

or:

```
let width = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(device.activeFormat.formatDescription as CMVideoFormatDescriptionRef!).width
let height = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(device.activeFormat.formatDescription as CMVideoFormatDescriptionRef!).height

myLayer?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGFloat(width), CGFloat(height))
```

Note that there is no implicit or explicit type casting between numeric types in swift, so you have to use the same pattern also for converting a `Int` to `Int32` or to `UInt` etc.

Comment: I wonder, is it safe to do this conversion on 32-bit systems, where `int32` is (still) 32 bits, however `CGFloat` is 32 bits too. Taking in account that latter is a floating point and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30260843/1492173), there will be a loss of precision. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I wonder why `let x: Int = 1; let y: Int = 2; let progress = CGFloat(x / y)` wasn't working for me. However, individually wrapping x and y as CGFloats worked.

Comment: @AndrewKirna not working because it doesn't compile, or because of an unexpected result? In the latter case, the result is 0.  `x` and `y` are `Int`, the division truncates, so `1 / 2 = 0` However if you convert at least one to CGFloat, the operands are both CGFLoat, so the expression evaluates to 0.5

Comment: @Antonio, it was because of an unexpected result. But that makes sense...I forgot all Integer division takes the floor of the result even though I'm converting the result to a CGFloat. In other words, the float version of 0 will still be 0.

Comment: Expression took 37ms to type-check (limit: 33ms)

Answer (score 3):

Just explicitly convert `width` and `height` to `CGFloat` using the `CGFloat's` initializer:

```
myLayer?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGFloat(width), CGFloat(height))
```