# Sorting Big Int value in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sorting

I have a problem to sort some numbers, which are string first. The numbers are too huge for UInt64, so i converted the string numbers to float and then sorted it. That works out great. But then i need to print these numbers with no decimals. So I tried to format the numbers. But the Bigger number are changing its value after formatting it.

Here is the Input array to sort -
["6","31415926535897932384626433832795","1","3","10","3","5"]

And I need to print output in exactly this format -

1

3

3

5

10

31415926535897932384626433832795

Here is my code in swift -

```
import Foundation
var a = Array<Float>()
var b = ["6","31415926535897932384626433832795","1","3","10","3","5"]
a = b.map{ Float($0)! }
for i in 0..<(a.count-1){
    var min = i
    for j in (i+1)..<a.count{
        if a[j] < a[min] {
            min = j
        }
    }

    var temp = a[i]
    a[i] = a[min]
    a[min] = temp
}
for val in a{
    print(String(format: "%.0f",val.rounded(.down)))
}
```

My Output is -

1

3

3

5

6

10

31415927314585224784361549725696

If you notice the last biggest number is changed from the original input. Any suggestions would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: The sorting has nothing to do with your issue. If you do your `for val in a{ print(String(format: "%.0f",val.rounded(.down)))}` before your sort (just after the `b.map{ Float($0)! }`), you'll notice the same issue.

Comment: Using `Float`, the sorted output of `["6","31415926535897932384626433832797","31415926535897932384626433832796","31415926535897932384626433832795","1", "3"]` is `["1", "3", "6", "31415926535897932384626433832797", "31415926535897932384626433832796", "31415926535897932384626433832795"]`. Can you accept this result?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30260769/converting-int-to-float-loses-precision-for-large-numbers-in-swift. This would help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With using float, you may get unexpected result for orders between big ints:

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
let inArray = [
    "6",
    "31415926535897932384626433832797",
    "31415926535897932384626433832796",
    "31415926535897932384626433832795",
    "1",
    "3"
]
let outArray = inArray.sorted {Float($0)! < Float($1)!}
print(outArray)
//->["1", "3", "6", "31415926535897932384626433832797", "31415926535897932384626433832796", "31415926535897932384626433832795"]
```

As described in mag_zbc's answer, `Float` has about only 7 significant digits, so all less significant digits are lost.

```
Float("31415926535897932384626433832797") == Float("31415926535897932384626433832795")
//->true
```

---

If the digits of your numbers are 38 at most, you can use `Decimal` (as also suggested in mag_zbc's answer).

```
let outWithDecimal = inArray.sorted {Decimal(string: $0)! < Decimal(string: $1)!}
print(outWithDecimal)
//->["1", "3", "6", "31415926535897932384626433832795", "31415926535897932384626433832796", "31415926535897932384626433832797"]
```

---

Or else, if your data contains numbers with more than 38 digits, `String` comparison would work with a little pre-processing:

(Assuming all your numbers are non-negative integer.)

```
extension String {
    func fillZeroLeft(_ length: Int) -> String {
        if self.characters.count < length {
            return String.init(repeating: "0", count: length-self.characters.count) + self
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }
}

let maxLen = inArray.lazy.map{$0.characters.count}.max()!
let outWithString = inArray.sorted {$0.fillZeroLeft(maxLen) < $1.fillZeroLeft(maxLen)}
print(outWithString)
//->["1", "3", "6", "31415926535897932384626433832795", "31415926535897932384626433832796", "31415926535897932384626433832797"]
```

(But numeric comparison in Sulthan's answer seems to be better for me!)

Comment: By the way, instead of padding the string with zeros, you can simply first compare the length, e.g. `sorted { $0.length < $1.length || $0 < $1 }`. (assuming positive integers).

Comment: @Sulthan, that seems to be a nice idea. But it seems to be missing some cases. Check if you can get a right result for `($0, $1) = ("123", "99")`.

Comment: My mistake, it would have to be `$0.length == $1.length ? $0 < $1 : $0.length < $1.length`.

Comment: @Sulthan, that should work. Or `{ $0.length < $1.length || $0.length == $1.length && $0 < $1 }` is equivalent.

Answer (score 5):

You can use numeric comparison:

```
let values = ["6","31415926535897932384626433832795","1","3","10","3","5"]

let sortedValues = values.sorted { (value1, value2) in
    let order = value1.compare(value2, options: .numeric)
    return order == .orderedAscending
}

print(sortedValues) // ["1", "3", "3", "5", "6", "10", "31415926535897932384626433832795"]
```

Comment: Playground execution failed: error: MyPlayground.playground:6:17: error: value of type 'String' has no member 'compare'
    let order = value1.compare(value2, options: .numeric)
                ^~~~~~ ~~~~~~~

Comment: @RichaSrivastava, you need to `import Foundation`.

Comment: Tested in both Swift 3 and Swift 4 environments, you probably need `Foundation` import.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to accurately represent such big numbers using primitive types in Swift.

Your value is ~3e+32
`UInt64` has a max value of ~1,8e+18
`Float` uses 24 bits for a significant, which allows to accurately represent a number up to ~1.6e+8
`Double` uses 53 bits for significant, which allows to accurately represent a number up to ~9e+15

Floating point types (`Float` and `Double`) are able to hold much greater values, but they will lose accuracy above the numbers their significants can hold.

Apart from using some external library, I'd suggest using `NSDecimalNumber` class, which is supposed to be able to hold up to 38 decimal digits - which is enough for numbers in your example. However, if you need even bigger numbers, then you'll need to look for some external library.

Comment: For float it is 3.402823e+38 and the number in question is less than that.

Comment: That's a maximum value `Float` can hold, I explicitly wrote I mean a maximum number you can **accurately** represent.

Comment: This is not the issue. Try with 31415926534. This will also lose.

Comment: That's to be expected - your number is ~3e+11, while maximum value `Float` can accurately represent is ~1.6e+8