# C# strange precision lost int to float and backwards

Tags: c#

curious thing happen when tried to cast from int to float and backwards.

Primitive example code:

> int val = 28218681;  // ***val=28218681***
>
> float fVal = (float) val; // ***fVal=2.821868E+07***
>
> int val2 = (int) fVal;    // ***val2=28218680***

May somebody explain why conversion lost rightmost "1" from value?

Thank You
Marius

Comment: I think you can find an answer to your question here, it's a different language but the same principles applys. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30260769/converting-int-to-float-loses-precision-for-large-numbers-in-swift

Comment: See - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/float - Note the precision is _"~6-9 digits"_ meaning not all 8 digit integers can be accurately represented as floats.

Comment: A `float` and and `int` both use 32 bits. However, an `int` can use ALL of those bits to represent its sign and value, whereas a `float` uses some of those bits for the floating point and mantissa which means it can't represent the same range of integer values - so it loses some precision.

Comment: Not an answer, but do use decimal over floats if you want precise fractions.

Comment: The float type has 24 bits available to represent a value, int has 31 bits.  So large values can't fit and have to be rounded.  The first time you'll lose a bit is at 2^24+1 = 16777217, try it.  Use double to get ahead, it can store 53 bits.  Or decimal, 96 bits, equivalent to 28 decimal digits.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen I would not call `2.821868E+07` a fraction. It is no more a fraction than `1E+30` is. But otherwise I agree with you.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen ah true, did not mean exactly fractions, but more precision when doing lets say financial or construction calculations.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen But we confuse things by discussing another problem. His example is a whole number. Whether to use binary or decimal is a different question than whether you use a type that is "wide" enough to have the desired precision. If the asker had used [`decimal32`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal32_floating-point_format) instead of `binary32`, he would have had __the exact same issue!__ Only the leading _seven_ decimal figures could be contained in the `decimal32`. His integer has _eight_ decimal figures. Same problem with decimal as with binary, for `28218681`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a comment to a now deleted answer:

The integer `28218681` can be written in binary as `1101011101001010100111001`. Note that 25 digits are needed. [Single precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) has only 24 bits for its "mantissa" (including the implicit leading 1 bit). 24 is less than 25. Precision is lost. A single-precision representation "remembers" a number only by its leading 24 binary digits. That corresponds to roughly 7-8 decimal figures. Roughly. The integer `28218681` has just 8 figures, so the problem arises.

---

The lesson learned is, use a type that is "wide" enough to give the desired precision. For example a `double` precision number can hold the first ~16 decimal figures of a number.

This is not related to the discussion on whether to use a binary or a decimal format. Note that if the asker had used [`decimal32`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal32_floating-point_format) instead of `binary32` (another name for `float`), he would have had the exact same issue!